# Строка размером 1px

Tags: html, css

```
<div>----</div>
```

Нужно сделать чтобы высота блока была равна одному **px**.

Comment: `height + line-height`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Получилось что-то такое) IE8, opera11, ff3.6

```
<div style="margin:0px;padding:0px;height:1px;line-height: 2px;font-family:'courier new';font-size:10px;overflow:hidden;">----</div>
```

Comment: Эм, или речь о ширине?

Answer (score 1):

```
div {
    background-color: red;
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
     font-size:1px;
}
```

font-size -> размер шрифта

кубиком красным выделен 1пиксель

Но толку - все равно ничего не увидишь ( я даже не наю как модно увеличить так браузерное окно, что бы 1пиксель был на весь монитор)